# Showing continuity of f

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have $f : (0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by

$$
f(x) = \frac{1}{1-x} - 2 , x \geq .5 \\
f(x) = -\frac{1}{x} + 2, x < .5
$$

I want to show it is continuous at $x = .5$. So this means I want to show $\lim_{x \rightarrow .5} f(x) = f(.5)$, or in other words $\forall\epsilon > 0. \; \exists \delta > 0. \; \forall x \in (0,1). \; 0 < |x - .5| < \delta \implies |f(x)| < \epsilon$.

My attempt proceeds as follows: let $\epsilon > 0$. Choose $\delta = \; ?$ (placeholder until the arithmetic reveals a good choice). Then case $x \geq .5$. So we have that $|f(x)| = |\frac{1}{1-x} - 2| < |\frac{1}{1-x}|$ (holds because $x \geq .5$) $ = \frac{1}{|1-x|} = \frac{1}{|x-1|}$. At this point it's not clear to me how to isolate the  $|x-.5|$ so I can apply the assumption. If I proceeded $\frac{1}{|x-1|} = \frac{1}{|x-.5-.5|}$, I can't apply triangle because I won't preserve the less than relationship.

This brings up another issue I'm confused about. So long as |x-.5| is in the denominator, if I try to apply $|x-.5| < \delta$, since $|x-.5|$ is in the denominator I will be increasing the overall value of the fraction and so I'll lose the chain of $<$, meaning I won't be able to show $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you guess what the common limit could be: guess $0$. So you need to show $\forall \epsilon$ $\exists \delta$ such that $|x-0.5|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)|<\epsilon$.

For $x\geq 0.5$, $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}-2=\frac{2x-1}{1-x}$. Choosing $\delta =\epsilon/8$, for any $x\in [0.5,0.5+\epsilon/8)$ you get
$$|f(x)|=\Big| \frac{2x-1}{1-x}\Big|\leq \frac{\epsilon/4}{0.5-\epsilon/8}=\frac{\epsilon}{2-\epsilon/2}< \epsilon.$$
Similarly for the other case $x<0.5$.

Comment: Why is $|1-x| \geq .5$?

Comment: If you make the denominator larger (e.g. by changing |1-x| to .5), you make the fraction smaller, and thus you don't have the $\leq$ relationship.

Comment: Oh sorry for the misunderstanding, answer edited.

Answer (score 0):

Both functions have a value for $x=0.5$, so the limit **is** this value. You just have to check that the value at $0.5$ is the same.

Comment: While I believe that $f$ is continuous at this point for this reason, this doesn't constitute a proof, without proving that piecewise defined functions with this property are continuous for that reason. Which doesn't really reduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have that
$$
\lim_{x\to\frac{1}{2}^+}f(x)=
\lim_{x\to\frac{1}{2}^+}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-2\right)=0
$$
and that
$$
\lim_{x\to\frac{1}{2}^-}f(x)=
\lim_{x\to\frac{1}{2}^-}\left(-\frac{1}{x}+2\right)=0
$$